# Add new page layout option Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, page-layouts

I'd like to add a new page layout in Magento that will be an option that can be selected in CMS pages. I have copied the `1-column.phtml` code and adapted it slightly and changed it to `1-column-version2.phtml.`

I'd like to know please how I would go about referencing the new file so that it appears in the ***CMS page layout options*.**

.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To meet your requirements you need to create an extension - without this it's not possible.

### Module config file :

Create the module file config  file at  `app/etc/modules/Amit_NewLayout.xml`

**Code:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Amit_NewLayout>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>local</codePool>
>             <depends>
>                 <Mage_Page />
>             </depends>
>         </Amit_NewLayout>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

### Define config.xml

Now  define `1-column-version2.phtml` as the template for the new layout in   `app/code/local/Amit/NewLayout/etc/config.xml`

**Code:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> 
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Amit_NewLayout>
>             <version>0.0.1</version>
>         </Amit_NewLayout>
>     </modules>
>     <global>
>         <page>
>             <layouts> 
>                 <new_cms_layout module="page" translate="label">
>                     <label>New Cms Layout</label>
>                     <template>page/1-column-version2.phtml</template>
>                     <layout_handle>lookbook</layout_handle>
>                 </new_cms_layout> 
>             </layouts>
>         </page>
>     </global>
> </config>
> ```

Now, you will be able to see this layout in the CMS page layout options.

Comment: Without this post, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create one module and add below xml in your config.xml file.

```
app/code/local/Namespace/CustomLayouts/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <global>
  <page>
   <layouts>
    <custom_static_page_one>
     <label>Custom static page</label>
     <template>page/1-column-version2.phtml</template>
    </custom_static_page_one>
   </layouts>
  </page>
 </global>
</config>
```

Register your module

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_CustomLayouts.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Namespace_CustomLayouts>
   <codePool>local</codePool>
   <active>true</active>
  </Namespace_CustomLayouts>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Create your own template file `page/1-column-version2.phtml`

Answer (score -3):

Add Your code in

```
app\code\core\Mage\Page\etc
```

`config.xml`:

with

```
 <My_one_column_cms module="page" translate="label">
        <label>My One Column</label>
        <template>page/home.phtml</template>
        <layout_handle>My_one_column_cms</layout_handle>
        </My_one_column_cms>
```

You can change names as ur wish in xml in  u can put any words

Then create home.phtml as your template in newtheme/newpack/page/ or ur default theme

Comment: Unwise to modify the core files.

Comment: You should never directly change the Core files. To elaborate, if you were to upgrade your Magento instance you would lose your changes. This is why you would create your own extension and implement like in Amit Bera's answer