# Create a custom layout - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

I have installed **Magento1.9.3.2**, I need to create a custom page layout like 1column,2columns,etc... I have tried something but he doesn't work properly.My frontend design displaying a **white page**.

My codes

**app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\layout\page.xml**

```
    <page_home translate="label">
        <label>Home Main</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>pages/home.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_home>
```

**app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\template\pages\home.phtml**

```
<div>
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Any one help.Advance thanks

Comment: Try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84969/add-new-page-layout-option-magento it can solve your problem

Comment: Ravi Ji create `.xml` file in modules folder. This is the path and see my code bellow `app/etc/modules/Custompage_Templates.xml`

Answer (score 5):

To create a new layout page, you have to create a new module like this:

Lets say that your new layout page call **1column-fullwidth**

**app/etc/modules/Custom_Column1Fullwidth.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
    <modules>
      <Custom_Column1Fullwidth>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Page />
        </depends>
    </Custom_Column1Fullwidth>
    </modules>
   </config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Column1Fullwidth/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
         <modules>
            <Custom_Column1Fullwidth>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Custom_Column1Fullwidth>
         </modules>
               <global>
                   <page>
                     <layouts>
                        <Column1Fullwidth translate="label">
                               <label>1Column-fullWidth</label>
                                 <template>page/1column-fullwidth.phtml</template>
                               <layout_handle>1column_full_width</layout_handle>
                        </Column1Fullwidth>
                     </layouts>
                   </page>
              </global>
     </config>
```

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/page/1column-fullwidth.phtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
    <head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
    </head>
    <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
        <div class="page">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer') ?>
            <div class="main-container col1-layout">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: its working. But front end displaying white background.how design my front page.

Comment: Yes, realy it displays a white background as default, now if you want to custom this background you have to change it in css

Comment: there is no content in my page how to add the content in my page

Comment: Your question is that you want to create a new page and put what you want on it, or create a new layout page ? Is not the same thing ?

Comment: i need to create new page layout and new page to connect with those two things. Now with your help i have created new page layout now i need to create the custom page .

Comment: Ok, now you have to create another module to have your new handle layout after that you will do something in xml (you set the new template in this layout handle) create your new module with a new page and then i'll tel you how to fi this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57032/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-and-prince).

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

`app/etc/modules/Custompage_Templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custompage_Templates>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Custompage_Templates>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: i have change the code like above,but in back end there is no new layout

Comment: check your file name, i mean `.xml` file name

Comment: I have created like this only but its not work

Answer (score 0):

change your layout as below

`app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\layout\page.xml`

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Home Main</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>pages/home.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: i have change the code like above,but in back end there is no new layout

Comment: ohk in backend where you want ?

Comment: CMS->Pages in pages->layouts