# Product Page Layout

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, template, xml, page-layouts

I'm trying to find a way to add a new custom layout for some products so I can just go to the Design Tab and choose the "Page Layout" from the dropout.
I can only find CMS Layout pages in google.
Also how do I then insert my own template files as view-custom.phtml, more-views-custom.phtml and media-bike.phtml.

I'm using version 1.9.1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of Magento is this for?

Comment: Edit it, ita v1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

1) To create a new template page, you can follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84971/48355)

2) To set a layout for some pages, you have to add this in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<your_layout_handle> //<catalog_category_default> for category page for exemple
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action> // 2columns-left.phtml for exemple
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>`
```

or

```
<your_layout_handle> //<catalog_category_default> for category page for exemple
    <action method="setTemplate" block="root">
        <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> // 2columns-left.phtml for exemple
    </action>
</your_layout_handle>
```