# Which files to update for a custom product layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

I want to create a new theme for custom layout on some product pages. 
I want to remove some items like minimum price.
Which files do I need to include in that theme.

(I wrote something here about that last night but cannot find it anymore)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a complete answer here because I need a little more information regarding the exact changes that you intend to make, and whether you are extending the base, rwd, or a third-party theme.  However, I'll give a general synopsis of important files, and hopefully we can expand from there.

Template files:
Basically, anything under `~/app/design/frontend/[custom]/[theme]/template/catalog/product` can be useful.

`template/catalog/product/view.phtml` is the main file
and most anything under `template/catalog/product/view` will be on the right side of a typical product-page, with the some exceptions, like `media.phtml`.

A great way to determine the files you want to copy into your subtheme is to turn on template hints under `System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Template` Path Hints.

***Note:***
This cannot be set at a default level, so make sure you switch to the website-scope before you look for this setting.

Another great tool that is not free, but will pay for itself with the time it saves you is [Commerce Bug](https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3/) by Alan Storm.

If you're looking for a which files are determined by Layout XML, the main handle is `catalog_product_view`, and `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple` can be useful, as well as `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`.  You can find these by searching in `~/app/design/frontend/[any]/[theme]/layout` "Find in files" in tools such as **Notepad++** or **Dreamweaver**, and here is a CLI command that I have found useful for finding handles, what is added to them, and where to find the template file:

```
grep -rn "path/to/search/in" -e 'string*and wildcards*to search for'
```

I am not sure that is is overly helpful, but maybe this can get you started, and I'll be happy to add more, if you have some specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

1 First you have to create your custom theme, assuming that your package/theme is called : `amthemes/prince`

2 You create a new custom layout for exemple: `app/design/frontend/amthemes/prince/template/page/2columns-left-new.phtml` follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84971/48355).

3 You define a new layout `2columns-left-new.phtml` for the product page like this:

`app/design/frontend/amthemes/prince/layout/local.xml` then you put the code bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default></default>
    <catalog_product_view> //the product view page
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left-new.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

4 you copy the **product page** from the other theme to the new one like this:

from :

`app/design/frontend/{otherPackage}/{otherTheme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

to :

`app/design/frontend/amthemes/prince/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and update what you want.